# Sum HashMap<String, List<CustomerDetail>> by lambda stream()

Tags: lambda, java-8, sum, java-stream

How can I sum point of customers by lambda stream `sum()`?

```
public class CustomerDetail {
    private int point = 1;
    private Integer id;

    public CustomerDetail() { 
        this(0);
    }
    public CustomerDetail(int id) { 
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPoint(int point) {
        this.point = point;
    }
    public int getPoint() {
        return point;
    }
}

HashMap<String, List<CustomerDetail>> list = new HashMap<String, List<CustomerDetail>>()
```

Comment: What is the point of having a `Map` here. Rather it should be a `List`. Also you have to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

You may do it like so,

```
int sumOfPoints = list.values().stream()
                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                         .mapToInt(CustomerDetail::getPoint)
                         .sum();
```